# Angular view data that was passed through a state on the route

Tags: angular, routes, state

I am trying to pass data from one page to another using routes. I found this website which is helpful:
https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

But I don't understand how they are calling the state on the page:

```
this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
  .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
```

If I add `console.log(this.state$)` I don't see the `hello: 'world'` that was passed from the route.
How do I view the actual data that was passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.state$` is an Observable. To view it's value you need to subscribe to it:

`this.state$.subscribe(state => console.log(state));`

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable

other than that: you're already piping the ActivatedRoute's ParamMap, so you might as well use it:

```js
this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    pluck('<your-param-key>'),
    map(valueFromKey => console.log(valueFromKey))
);
```

Comment: Both code examples cause errors. The first code trying to subribe returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" and the code using pluck returns this error: Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<object>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'object'

Comment: you have to define `this.state$` before you subscribe to it... btw I think you can omit the whole paramMap stuff and use `window.history.state` synchronously

Comment: Ok the line `this.state$.subscribe(state => console.log(state));` works now when placed under the `window.history.state` code. But the console.log returns the whole object. How do I just see the value? i.e. I just want to see "world"

Comment: either use pluck or do `state.hello` in the subscribe callback

Comment: If you want to use the state observable directly in the view and extract one of its fields, try `{{ (state$ | async)?.hello }}` .

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data which is send with the router easily as follows using **`ActivatedRoute`**

### Query Param Method

**`app.component.ts`**

```
this.router.navigate(["page1"], { queryParams: { app: "Angular" } });
```

**`page1.component.ts`**

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((item: any) => {
      console.log(item);
      this.routerVariable = item;
    });
}
```

### State Method

**`page1.component.ts`**

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
     console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
}
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
this.router.navigate(["page1"], { state: { path: "app" } });
```

check the working `stackblitz` example here : **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jykppc?file=src/styles.css**

Comment: I don't want the paramater to appear in the URL which was why I was trying to send the data through the state and then call the state on the other page

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your request @user123456789

Comment: you are not subscribing for different state values, is it posible ?